# Strange Pico GPIO pulses

Tags: c, gpio, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to make a Pico program for a series of WS2812 LEDS. Before my Pico sends the correct signals, it give me long pulses to the left of the center in the picture. Everything to the right works as intented, I can't find what is causing this.

[image: Osilloscope Screenshot]

```
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
int main() {
    const uint GREENDO = 16;
    const uint BLUEBO = 17;
    const uint LEDPIN = 25;
    gpio_init(LEDPIN);
    gpio_init(GREENDO);
    gpio_init(BLUEBO);
    gpio_set_dir(GREENDO, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_set_dir(BLUEBO, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_set_dir(LEDPIN, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_put(LEDPIN,1);
    gpio_put(BLUEBO,0);
    gpio_put(GREENDO,0);

    int GRBValues[] ={1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,};
    int CurBit = 1;
    for (size_t Index = 0; Index < 6; Index++){
        for (size_t BitIndex = 0; BitIndex < 25; BitIndex++){
            CurBit = GRBValues[BitIndex];
            if (CurBit == 1){
                //800-450
                gpio_put(GREENDO,1);
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
               asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\n");
                gpio_put(GREENDO,0);
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\n");
            }else{
                //400-850
                gpio_put(GREENDO,1);
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                gpio_put(GREENDO,0);
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n");
                asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\n");
            }             
          /*  if (BitIndex == 0){
                sleep_us(51);   //Test to fix problem, did not work
              }*/
        }          
    }
    while (true){
        gpio_put(LEDPIN,0);
        sleep_ms(1000);
        gpio_put(LEDPIN,1);
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

- I tried adding a delay after the first bit by 51us but I would then recive the unintentinal pulses again
- I also tried for loops that are empty and with junk data in them but then all bits were too long.

This might have something to do with starting a new for loop iteration after some time has passed, and if so, why not on every new for iteration.

Comment: Does that happen when you power on your micro? Is there some Bootstrap mechanism active that might share the pin you are using for your LED?

Comment: Single step though the program including the CRT, while watching the signal on the scope. Should be trivial to find the culprit that way.

Comment: To make it more readable: Can't you put that truck load of `nop` into a loop where you just need to adjust the limit for the counter instead of copying yet another line.

Comment: You have `gpio_init(); gpio_set_dir(); gpio_put();`, how do you know that GPIO line state is persist among these calls?

Comment: Gerhardh I previously had a sleep_ms(2500) between the for loops and the pin setup, I can't use for loops because they are too long apprently and I can't get the percision in timing.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are too long"? How long is one iteration of `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){asm volatile ("nop\nnop\nnop\n");}` ? If you cannot get it precise enough, then just do one iteration less and add a few single `nop`s as you do now.